# How can I take string input for UVA online problem for java only ? Detail information needed

Tags: java, arrays, user-input, readline, eof

I am trying to string input for UVA online judge problem using JAVA.

like C++

```
while(s = getchar()) {
   if(s == EOF)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a string.");
String str = scanner.nextLine();
```

Is this what you're looking for? If you're reading from a file,

```
import java.io.File;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("path.txt"));
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String str = scanner.nextLine();
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using the following

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

while (stdin.hasNextLine()) 
{
  String line = stdin.nextLine();
  // Further Opera
}
```